# Import.io doesn't find the links

Tags: import.io

I use import.io desktop extractor to extract links from this page:
http://plusaccessible.org/yakaldir/html/arts_litterature.htm

It extract only titles of links:

1. QuestionVoyage
2. forum.baroussemania.com
3. Saint-Martin
4. AmieZ
5. Forum Russie
6. Forum tourisme
7. Teranga Senegal - forum du Sénégal
8. Billet d'avion
9. le Maroc

But it doesn't extract the urls inside the href="".

If I add the xpath myself:

```
 /html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a[1]
```

It give the same url for all the links

If I add

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/a
```

It gives all the urls for each links:

1. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
2. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
3. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
4. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
5. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes

   6. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
      RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
      d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
      voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
      dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
      CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
      vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
6. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
7. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
8. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
   RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
   d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
   voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
   dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
   CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
   vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes

   10. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   11. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   12. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   13. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   14. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   15. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   16. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   17. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   18. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes
   19. QuestionVoyageforum.baroussemania.comSaint-MartinAmieZForum
       RussieForum tourismeTeranga Senegal - forum du SénégalBillet
       d'avionle MarocForum sur la GrèceInfo location de vacancesCarnet de
       voyages Chris2neuXA tous les bouts du mondeRésidences de vacances
       dans le monde entierAnnuaire des Hébergements - inn26.comTaxi C.
       CadetLocFrance Annonces de location de vacancesLocasun - Locations
       vacancesAtouts Loisirs - HolidaysHomes

So my question is how can I extract the links with url of this page?

Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to extract all the links on the page? If so, you can try a much simple xpath expression:

```
//a[@href]
```

That should select all `<a>` elements, no matter where in the page, and then extract the `href` attribute from them.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn work. Import.io works fine for many dirctories but not this one.

Comment: Make sure that you've selected "link" not "text" while training the columns.